# Could be Text orientation of JTextArea changed by keyboard shortcut?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, jtextarea, text-alignment

A JTextArea has componenent orientation set to LEFT, so text is written from left to right. Sometimes, it happens that while the user is writing, the text orientation suddenly changes to right, so all the text appears aligned to right.
I can't explain why this happens (I have no direct feedback by users), but I guess that, while the user is typing, he activates some keyboard shortcut which changes the text orientation. 
Does someone know how this can happen? Can be there something else which triggers the change of text orientation in a text area?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Swing has predefined keyboard shortcuts which activates within the creation of swing objects. You should edit your key bindings. [This article](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) is useful for your situation.

Comment: (1+) in particular it looks like "shift control O" will toggle the component orientation.

Comment: Yes, the component orientation is changed by Ctrl+Shift+O. The point is that the orientation does not change immediately, but after you start typing something.