# Java Swing - text component accidentally switched to RTL

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, right-to-left

This is `JTextArea` I think or `JEditorPane`. There must be a keyboard shortcut installed - but I can't figure out which - that switches from LTR to RTL layout. Suddenly the words of sentences come out in reverse order and right aligned. What is that "default" keyboard shortcut, and can I switch back in a running application?

Answer (score 0):

As a comment under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37302513/could-be-text-orientation-of-jtextarea-changed-by-keyboard-shortcut#37302785) points out, the shortcut is <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd>